# Dell Computers (Motherboard / NIC) retain Static IP address even after HDD is removed

Tags: windows, ip, dell, nic, static-ip

So many of our Dell computers (NIC or Motherboard) seem to be holding onto the Static IP Address set within windows. When we decide to put a different hard drive into the computer and re-image it, we are unable to PXE boot with SCCM because SCCM detects that the computer is still set the static IP address that was assigned within Windows of the Old HDD. PXE booting works fine for all computers set to DHCPs.

We have noticed this issue for a while now, but it's potentially very dangerous, if there is no real solution. We could technically not be able to image the computer if we ever forget to set the IP to DHCP in windows before removing the old harddrive and installing a new one.

Has anyone seen this before or familiar with anything regarding this sort of issue?

Comment: Try changing it's MAC address if possible. I've definitely used networks that always allocate the same IP address for each HW address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible for the NIC to retain any IP information in this way. What's more likely is the DHCP server configuration.

Some useful information to know would be:

- Do the computers that had static addresses have DHCP reservations? These are tied to the MAC address, so the same IP would be given to the host after re-image.
- Is the PXE server IP address being provided to DHCP clients in the Option 60 field of the DHCP offer?
- Is the PXE service on the same server as the DHCP server?